I have a question of Prop.9.2 of Atiyah's commutative algebra.
I have a question of proof of Prop9.2 (iii)
$\Rightarrow$(iv).
Prop.9.2. Let A be a Noetherian local domain of dimention one, $\mathfrak{m}$ its maximal ideal, k = $A/\mathfrak{m}$ its residue field.
Remark.(B) $\mathfrak{m}^n \neq \mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ for all $n \geqq 0$.
Proof.(iii) $\Rightarrow$(iv).
By Prop2.8 we have dim$_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) \leqq 1$, and by remark(B) $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \neq 0$.
I don't know why can I use Prop2.8 to make that  dim$_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) \leqq 1$ is concluded.
Prop2.8. Let $A$ be local ring, $\mathfrak{m}$ its macimal ideal, $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$ its residue field. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. Let $x_i(1 \leqq i \leqq n)$ be elements of $M$ whose images in $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ from a basis of this vector space. Then the $x_i$ generate $M$.

The key here is that $\mathfrak{m} = \langle g \rangle$, since $A$ is one-dimensional; this uses the Principal Ideal Theorem.

You want to show that $M/M^2$ is at most a one-dimensional space over the field $k=A/M$. Since we are assuming (in that proposition) that $M$ is principal ideal, we can find $g\in M$ so that $M = Ag$. The goal is to now show that $(g \bmod M^2)$ is generator for $M/M^2$ i.e. the dimension of $M/M^2$ is at most $1$.
To that end, pick $*\in M/M^2$, so $* = (x\bmod M^2)$ for some $x\in M$. Since $M = Ag$ we can further write $x = ag$ for some $a\in A$, and so $* = (ag\bmod M^2) = \underbrace{(a\bmod M)}_{\in ~ A/M = k} \cdot \underbrace{(g\bmod M^2)}_{\in ~  M/M^2}$
In particular, every element $*$ in the space $M/M^2$ is a scalar multiple of $(g\bmod M^2)$.

I don't know about dimention of ring very well, so I don't know why since (g mod M^2) is generator for M/M^2, the dimension of M/M^2 is at most 1.

@aaaba If $V$ is a vector space over $k$, do you know what it means for $\dim(V) = 1$?

I could understand dim(M/M^2)=1. I mistake dimention of module for Krull dimention. Thank you.

@aaaba Is the answer clear? Do you need more help?

No. I don't. I could solve this question  because of you.

@aaaba No, not because of me, because of you. You are tremendous. I just helped you a little bit. But you are the only who did the hard work. You did 99% of the work.
